# Drupal 8 : How can I override module file in my custome theme

Tags: overriding, drupal-8, drupal-modules

How can I override below file in my custom theme

`web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/templates/commerce-checkout-form--with-sidebar.html.twig`

Anyone any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Try copy commerce-checkout-form--with-sidebar.html.twig from your contrib module and place it in templates folder in your custom theme.